# Layout update: unable to add a child block in layout XML by reference

Tags: layout, layout-update

I'm having a problem where I can't seem to add a child block in a layout XML file. What am I doing wrong in `mylayout.xml` that I can't load `abc`? I have the following files.

onestepcheckout.xml

```
<onestepcheckout_index_index>
    ...
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="onestepcheckout/checkout" name="onestepcheckout.checkout" template="onestepcheckout/checkout.phtml">
            ...
            <!-- this child block can be loaded -->
             <block type="block/class" template="path/to/template/template.phtml" name="qwe" as="qwe" />
            ...
        </block>
    </reference>
    ...
</onestepcheckout_index_index>
```

mylayout.xml

```
<onestepcheckout_index_index>
    <reference name="onestepcheckout.checkout">
        <!-- this child block can not be loaded -->
        <block type="block/class" template="path/to/template/template.phtml" name="abc" as="abc" />
    </reference>
</onestepcheckout_index_index>
```

checkout.phtml

```
...
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('abc') // doesn't work ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('qwer') // works ?>
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out why. My extension loads first, and the extension that loads onestepcheckout_index_index is loaded after mine. Therefore, my layout update was referring to a handle that doesn't exist yet..

Answer (score 8):

If its a module loading issue, I think you should add a  tag in your module declaration file. like below

`<depends>
  <companyname_modulename/>
</depends>`

This will insure that your module will be loaded after companyname_modulename

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify this. Several steps were necessary. First, declare the block as a child block.

```
<action method="setChild"><alias>my_name</alias><child>my.name</child></action>
```

Then add the dependency to your module declaration file. In my case it was `Idev_OneStepCheckout`

```
<depends>
    <Idev_OneStepCheckout />
</depends>
```

Finally, in the template it will only work if you use the alias.

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('my_name')
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why that doesn't work either.  Have you tried explicitly declaring the block as a child?

```
<onestepcheckout_index_index>
    <reference name="onestepcheckout.checkout">
        <!-- this child block can not be loaded -->
        <block type="block/class" template="path/to/template/template.phtml" name="abc" as="abc" />
        <action method="setChild"><child>abc</child><alias>abc</alias></action>
    </reference>
</onestepcheckout_index_index>
```

Comment: I tried it, but it still doesn't work. The strange thing is that I have other updates in `my layout.xml` that uses the same method, and they all work.

Comment: I found out why. My extension loads first, and the extension that loads `onestepcheckout_index_index` is loaded after mine. Therefore, my layout update was referring to a handle that doesn't exist yet..

Comment: @laketuna that's very interesting, i had a similar problem recently and just used an observer, but this question sparked my curiosity again, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add new block, you should reference structural blocks, not content blocks. Try out something like this instead:

```
<onestepcheckout_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="block/class" template="path/to/template/template.phtml" name="abc" as="abc" />
    </reference>
</onestepcheckout_index_index>
```

Comment: Referring to `content` loads my block, but I can't control where the block gets placed if I refer to `content.

Comment: It gets placed by `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('abc') ?>`

Comment: I need to place this block in a specific location. As far as I know, referencing `content` places the block automatically and `echo $this->getChildHtml('abc')` has no effect. Correct me if I'm wrong.